# Editing and playing real time PCM

Tags: c++, audio, cross-platform

I'm doing an acoustic waves simulation using c++, I get the raw PCM data form wav file and apply some calculation on it then I want to play it in real time also I want to recalculate these data when the user changes some values in the simulation (like his location).

I tried the `Portaudio` library the played sound was a kind of noise and it seems that I have to use `Pa_Sleep` which is blocking the user interactive with my program.

Is `Portaudio` the right library to work with ? or there is another solution to get this done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [JACK Audio Connection Kit](http://jackaudio.org). Be sure to check the link saying 'Docs' at the top of the page, there's a walkthrough for generating a simple client.